# In C# (WPF) column names of DataGrid Header

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

How do I get the Column Name of a `DataGrid` `Header`?
I need to do searching on individual data field of the `Grid`. 
At the same time I need to know its Datatype too.

My SQL fields and Grid columns are passed to the query as:

```
string FieldHeaders = "UserID as 'User ID', " + 
                      "Password as Password, " + 
                      "UserName as 'User Name', " + 
                      "PrivilegeLevel as 'Privilege Level', " + 
                      "CreationDate as 'Creation Date', " +                           
                      "LastTimeLogin as 'Last Login Time', " + 
                      "ExpireyDate as 'Expirey Date'";
```

Comment: Please post the code that you have.

Comment: That's not helpful, other than showing us you're using string concatenation to create your query, which might be a bad thing based on how the query itself is finally constructed.  We can't know until you post the relevant code, and include it as a code object on the site ({} in the edit menu).

Comment: I incorporated your comment into your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
//gets the type of the first datagrid column
var type = UsersDg.Columns.First().GetType();
//gets the name of the first column header
var hd = UsersDg.Columns.First().Header;
```

Answer (score 0):

To those who are interested to get the name of any column in a Datagrid.  Just use (Sorting) event handler as follows:

```
    private void Dg_Sorting(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
    {
        LblSearchField.Content = e.Column.Header.ToString();
    }
```

Once a datagrid column is pressed the required Label(LblSearchField) would hold the field name.  From there you could do your searching any field you require.

Good programming day.